# How to disable Ctrl+Q in Obsidian

Tags: obsidian

I have customized my Obsidian key bindings to a large degree, so I am familiar with how changing key bindings works. However, I recently noticed that in Obsidian 1.1.16 (on Linux) `Ctrl+Q` will exit the application and this shortcut is nowhere mentioned in the settings or the documentation, and so it seems I cannot disable it(?) This is unfortunate because in other applications I'm used to hit `Ctrl+Q` for different purposes, so I keep on accidentally quitting Obsidian.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm writing this question I managed to come up with a workaround: Just bind something else (possibly nonsensical) to `Ctrl+Q` in the settings. This will at least prevent the application from exiting!